# Translation Workbench running into APEX Cpu Limit

Tags: translation-workbench

I am unable to override a custom field label using Translation Workbench's 'Override' functionality. Anyone familiar with this error?

This is the error that Salesforce runs into:

```
Error is in expression ‘{!ValidateAndLoadSetupEntity}’ in page LabelWorkbenchOverride.apexp: (System Code)
```

Comment: Can you add the steps you are following to reproduce the error? Also, is there a managed package involved?

Comment: I could not reproduce your error message when I followed steps> Navigated to /lightning/setup/LabelWorkbenchOverride/home. Selected Salesforce CPQ managed package. language as German. selected Setup Component> custom field

Comment: Yes, this happened when we were trying to override Custom Fields. And there were several managed packages installed.

Comment: Can you clarify which specific managed package it is so I can try from my end to reproduce the error?

Comment: Accounting Seed managed package

Comment: I have tried with the Accounting Seed managed package for custom field and do not see any errors. Can you state which specific master field label is throwing error?